# install kmymoney 4.8.1 on kubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, source, kmymoney

I have Kubuntu 18.04 and Kmymoney 5.0 installed. Now I discovered a bug. I can’t see the stock quotes which you can see here https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/extragear-office/kmymoney/details.investments.securities.html. Now I know that there is no bug in 4.8.1. Now my question is: how can I install kmymoney 4.8.1 in Kubuntu 18.04 from the source via https://download.kde.org/stable/kmymoney/4.8.1/src/ .

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you filed a bug report?

Comment: no, not yet, but I will!

Answer (score 1):

First of all download the file in the link and follow the steps listed below:

**Source**: README.cmake in the archive.

### Quick-start 0: Precondition

Check that cmake is installed on your machine and is in your PATH.
To do so, just type

```
$ cmake --version
```

on your command line. Version 2.6.4 is required, the most recent
stable version of cmake is preferred.

For debian/Ubuntu user the following command will check for 
required packages to build KMyMoney:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep kmymoney
```

---

### Quick-start 1: Build KMyMoney

cmake is designed so that the build process can be done in a separate
directory. This is highly recommended for users and required for packagers.

Go to the top level of the git working directory.
To build KMyMoney in the subdirectory ./build/ type

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
```

`$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` to generate the Makefiles.

`$ ccmake .` to change the configuration of the build process. (optional)

Congratulations, your Makefiles were generated!
Now you could just type

`$ make`
    to build the project in the build/ directory.

Note that 'make' automatically checks whether any CMakeLists.txt file
has changed and reruns cmake if necessary.

`$ make install`
    to install the project. You have to install KMyMoney to run it. 
Use `sudo` or switch to a superuser to run this command.

Congratulations, you will never have a chaos of generated files
between the important source files again!

---

### Quick-start 2: How to compile Debug-Builds

As an example configuration option, you would like to configure a
debug build just as './configure --enable-debug=full' did before.

For this, you can conveniently create a new out-of-source build directory:

```
$ mkdir Debug
$ cd Debug
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debugfull ..
```

Instead of the last command, you could also call CMake without command
line arguments and use the GUI to switch the build type.

```
$ cmake ..
$ ccmake .

and change the option CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to 'Debugfull'.  Selecting
an option and pressing 'h' will show you its allowed values.
```

In any case, your choices are safely stored in the file CMakeCache.txt
which will never be completely overwritten.
If you want to reset your changes, you will have to delete this file.

---

### Quick-start 3: More options

- `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path_to_install_dir>`
  This option tells cmake where to install KMyMoney to.
  During development, this should be a directory in your development
  environment, such that you can debug the program and test the
  installation.
  The default is `${KDE3PREFIX}`, which is usually `"/opt/kde3/"`.
- `DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<type>`
  Choose the type of build. Possible values are:
    'Release' 'RelWithDebInfo' 'Debug' 'Debugfull' 'Profile'
  The default value is: 'RelWithDebInfo'
- `DKDE4_BUILD_TESTS=ON`
  To also build the unit tests.

---

### Quick-start 4: Makefile targets

After cmake has finished, you have a set of ordinary Makefiles in your
directory.  You can type

`$ make help`
    to see all available make targets in the current directory.

`$ make`
    to reconfigure the Makefiles and build the project.

`$ make install`
    to install KMyMoney to the directory CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

`$ make DESTDIR=/tmp install`
    to install KMyMoney to the directory /tmp/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

`$ make uninstall`
    to uninstall a previous installation.

`$ make package`
    to create a binary tarball.

`$ make package_source`
    to create a source tarball.
    (Warning: must have a clean source directory and build out-of-source)

```
$ make kmymoney-unstable_rpm
$ make kmymoney_rpm
```

to create binary rpm packages.
    (they only differ in the package name)

```
$ make kmymoney_srpm
$ make kmymoney-unstable_srpm
```

to create source rpm packages.

`$ make messages`
    to extract and merge translations.
    (Warning: This will change the source files)

`$ make developer-doc`
    to create the developer handbook. Will also create HTML-version.

`$ make test`
    to process all unit tests.