# Install KMyMoney Basics - Compile?

Tags: compiling, git, cmake, kde-apps, kmymoney

I'm a new user in Ubuntu 18.04. I'd like to install the latest KMyMoney and I've looked at some advanced discussions, but I need something basic. For instance:

1. Must I compile anything? I understand I need some KDE tools but must I compile them or just install them?
2. This recent link ([install kmymoney 4.8.1 on kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048767/install-kmymoney-4-8-1-on-kubuntu-18-04)) suggests I also need "git." Is that true for my install? I do want to be able to update it with security and bug fixes and possible improvements in the future.
3. If #2 above is necessary, then can someone point me to some really beginner knowledge of Git?
4. Is KMyMoney available by apt-get or is this something I must download and process?

Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt install kmymoney` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kmymoney

Comment: Thank you, that worked. You'd think that would be the first search result on the web for "ubuntu install kmymoney".

Comment: Ubuntu packages foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install as much as possible from the ubuntu repositories.

To find packages search here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com

Kmymoney is in the repos

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kmymoney

So ....

```
sudo apt install kmymoney
```